# Ordering Glossary in ToC before another entry

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

I'm having difficulties getting my glossary to show up in the right place in my table of contents. It needs to come before the Acknowledgements and be in the same font type as the List of Figures etc.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[acronym,toc]{glossaries}  %Allows creation of a glossary page
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Ppump}
 {
  name=$P_{Pump}$,
  description={Pump wavelength (W)}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%         Begin document              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\doublespacing
\include{abstract}
\include{table_of_contents}
\singlespacing
\include{acknowledgements}

\end{document}
```

And for additional info, this is the code for my ToC (table_of_contents.tex).

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Sets up Table of Contents            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Glossary of Terms}
\printglossaries

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
```

I am working on my thesis, so I do have quite a few .tex files for the different sections to make debugging easier (at least for me) as most of them are just different chapters then I can include them into the main document later. Anyways, if this question has already been asked, can someone please refer me to the link?

Comment: Why are you adding everything manually to the table of contents rather than letting LaTeX handle most (if not all) of it? If you are going to add things with `\addcontentsline`, then you either need to avoid altogether the standard sectioning commands or you need to redefine them so that they don't also try to add entries. The former will work (I just created a 200+ thing relying almost entirely on this method - though not for the glossary, I admit) but the latter is a lot easier if that's an option. Do you really want 'contents' to appear in your table of contents? Why?

Comment: In any case, please correct your MWE. It will not compile without error right now.

Comment: The title "Contents" does not appear in the ToC but "Table of Contents" must. It's part of the thesis guidelines for my university. I only put these ones in manually. The chapters and other subsections (which I have not included here) automatically get added to the ToC. Does this answer your question @cfr?

Comment: Not really. Why are you adding glossaries etc. manually?

Comment: As it is, LaTeX is doing just as you've told it. It is adding the contents line for the glossary. It is then adding it again when you issue `\printglossaries` because you have asked `glossaries` to put the glossary in the table of contents. Either remove the `toc` option or remove the manual addition and configure the `toc` option to behave as you wish.

Comment: I still think adding the ToC to the ToC is excessively self-referential but if the thesis rules say you must dare the dangers of paradox, say no more: dare them you must. (I just hope your thesis is not on the topic of barbers.)

Comment: That comment was quite rude. Clearly, I did not understand what you were asking and I am relatively new to LaTeX. I thought you were asking "Why is the contents in my table of contents?" and not "Why are you calling the glossary to the Table of Contents twice?".

Comment: I'm sorry if you felt it was rude. It was not intended to be. You asked if that answered my question. It didn't so I clarified the question and explained I was asking again by saying you hadn't answered (what I'd meant by) my question. I didn't mean anything by it except what it said. You'd not understood what I'd meant to ask. That could be my fault or yours or both. (But I'm not sure 'fault' is relevant here: misunderstandings are a pervasive feature of human existence, especially on the net.) I just wanted to know to see how best to solve the problem. As I say, I'm sorry you found it rude.

Comment: It was mostly the barber part. The rest of your suggestions were helpful. Thank you. Unfortunately I had to leave before I could re-edit my MWE, but it was a nice surprise to see you generate an example upon my return. It helped a lot and helped me find my mistake, so thanks again.

Comment: Hmm. OK. I didn't realise you meant that comment. That wasn't meant to be rude either. Actually, that didn't occur to me. I may have a twisted sense of humour, though. Have you heard of Russell's paradox? It is connected with that. The story involves a barber who shaves all those who do not shave themselves. Does the barber shave himself? It was just that a rule requiring you to put the ToC in itself reminded me of the paradoxes arising from naïve set theory and, hence, the barber.

Comment: I can completely see finding the comment irrelevant and unamusing. I'm a bit mystified that you found it rude. But I'm still sorry that you did find it rude.

Comment: Oh ok. Everything makes sense now. My apologies :-) and thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently adding the glossary to the table of contents twice. The first time is when you add the contents line manually. The next is when you issue `\printglossaries` having passed the `toc` option to `glossaries`.

## Method 1

Don't pass `toc` to `glossaries`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{table_of_contents.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Sets up Table of Contents            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Glossary of Terms}
\printglossaries

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abstract.tex}
    abstract
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{acknowledgements.tex}
    acknowledgements
\end{filecontents}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}  %Allows creation of a glossary page
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Ppump}
 {
  name=$P_{Pump}$,
  description={Pump wavelength (W)}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%         Begin document              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\include{abstract}
\include{table_of_contents}
\include{acknowledgements}

\gls{Ppump}

\begin{figure}
    my figure
    \caption{exciting figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        a   &   table
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{exciting table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Manual addition]

## Method 2

Configure `toc` to behave as you wish:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{table_of_contents.tex}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%           Sets up Table of Contents            %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Table of Contents}
\tableofcontents

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Figures}
\listoffigures

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of Tables}
\listoftables

\clearpage
\printglossary[title={Glossary of Terms}]

\newpage
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Acknowledgements}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abstract.tex}
    abstract
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{acknowledgements.tex}
    acknowledgements
\end{filecontents}

\pagestyle{plain}

\usepackage[acronym, toc, section=section]{glossaries}  %Allows creation of a glossary page
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{Ppump}
 {
  name=$P_{Pump}$,
  description={Pump wavelength (W)}
 }

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%         Begin document              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\pagenumbering{roman}

\include{abstract}
\include{table_of_contents}
\include{acknowledgements}

\gls{Ppump}

\begin{figure}
    my figure
    \caption{exciting figure}
\end{figure}
\begin{table}
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
        a   &   table
    \end{tabular}
  \caption{exciting table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Configure automatic addition]

Comment: See previous comment, but thank you for your suggestions. They worked.

Comment: This comment was the most helpful: "You are currently adding the glossary to the table of contents twice. The first time is when you add the contents line manually. The next is when you issue \printglossaries having passed the toc option to glossaries."

Comment: @Kim See comment on previous comment. I'm glad it worked.